# Are relays appropriate? circuit review

Tags: switches, relay, dc-motor

I'm designing a circuit to drive two 12V dc motors.
I've got two low current switches connected to relays as can be seen in the schematic. These are for power isolation and local motor isolation.

Can you tell me if relays are an appropriate switching mechanism for these loads?

Considering the 24V relaym aware a typical 24V relay requires 200mA to drive. Is there something else I should be using with less current drain? (more battery life - I'm using two 12V lead acid batteries)

[image: Segway schematic]

Comment: The question is how much amps you switch and what relays you use (i.e. if they are suited for those amps and inductive loads).

Comment: The motors will be approx. 28A at full load. Am I correct in saying that a typical relay needs approx 200mA to drive? Considering that RY1 will be constantly active and RY2 close behind, are relays the best choice here when aiming to conserve battery power?

Comment: and then you worry about an additional 200mA ? Also you probably want a contactor instead of a simple relay then

Comment: What is the LRA (stall current) rating on the motors? What is the relay rating?

Comment: I didn't go for a simple switch as opposed to relay as there was potential to be driving high currents (28A). Would a switch better then?

Comment: @adamp524: your deadman's switch must cut power to the motors in a failsafe fashion. e.g., A micro-controller output transistor is not considered fail-safe. It could fail open or short. Similarly any relays must be safety rated too. Have a look for machine e-stop and safety circuits references. Your safety must be hard-wired and not through a logic controller.

Comment: What is the "motor controller" in use here? As Olin said, RY2 seems reasonable to me, as long as you wire it correctly (it should be ON by default, only OFF when you press the kill switch, unless you are doing the opposite on purpose).

Answer (score 3):

RY1 seems silly since S3 can perform its function directly, unless the issue is that you can't find a suitable switch to handle the current.  A relay will be more expensive than just a switch of the same rating.

However, RY2 looks like a reasonable use of a relay.  This is assuming the motors are not "frequently" switched on and off, like they would be with PWM control.  Of course the relays need to be rated for the maximum motor current, which will occur when first turned on.  This is often called the "stall current".  See the motor datasheet.

The resistor in series with the RY2 coil doesn't make sense.  From the labels, it appears you are driving the relay from 5 V.  Get a relay with a 5 V coil.  Most relays come in a family with the only difference being the coil voltage.  5 V is a common voltage, so you should not have trouble finding the right relay.  200 mA also sounds high unless this relay needs to handle 10s of A.

You might also consider a snubber across the relay contacts.  That will extend life.  If the motors are driven with DC and only one polarity, then a reverse diode across each motor will also help.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comments
Yes RY1 is purely for switching the whole circuit on and off. A relay and small switch was looking cheaper than a single switch which would handle 30A.

Looking at RY2, the motors will not be regularly switched on and off i.e. PWM.

Can you explain what a snubber would be across the relay contacts?